# External display periodically enters power save mode when running on battery power

Tags: display, battery, sleep-wake

Normally I have my MacBook Pro connected to power when it is on its external display, but at the moment I'm using it without the adapter, with an external mouse, keyboard, and display (a Dell U2515H through an HDMI cable).

Every couple of minutes or so the **display enters power save mode and the keyboard becomes unresponsive**; then after about another minute they switch on again.

**Q: What is causing this behavior and how can I fix it?**

I've already tried System Preferences > Energy Saver and increased the "Turn display off after" to 1 hour, but that seems not to help.

This question is similar to [How to avoid external display going off after I unplug a MacBook from the AC Power?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199439/how-to-avoid-external-display-going-off-after-i-unplug-a-macbook-from-the-ac-pow), which is so far unanswered.

Comment: Please let us know the exact hardware and OS you are using (e.g. MacBook 2016, macOS 10.13.1)